# Django REST framework FileField PUT Testcase

Tags: django-rest-framework, filefield, django-unittest

I have a model that contains a FileField which may not be blank. When creating tests for this model, I've run into the problem that I get errors when testing with PUT, while the exact same thing works when doing a POST. 
As views I'm simply using `generics.ListCreateAPIView` for the POST destination and `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` for the PUT destination, both work normally when using the API in browser.

The payload for the POST and PUT is created as follows:

```
uploaded_file = SimpleUploadedFile('TestCode4.c', "Testcode", content_type='text/plain')
self.valid_payload = {
    'name': 'TestValid',
    'test_file': uploaded_file
}
```

Then the working POST test looks as follows:

```
client = Client()
response = client.post(
    reverse('code-list'),
    self.valid_payload,
    format='json'
)
```

And the PUT:

```
client = Client()
response = client.put(
    reverse('code-detail', kwargs={'pk': 1}),
    self.valid_payload,
    format='json'
)
```

The POST returns 204 and creates a new object, while the PUT returns 415 with the following error:

```
{u'detail': u'Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.'}
```

I am unsure what is going wrong here, it seems that both the post and put are passing the `SimpleUploadedFile` data in the same way, though with put it somehow becomes an octet stream.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem Django's `django.test.Client` class does not support the 'PUT' method. Instead the REST framework provides the class `rest_framework.test.APIClient`, which does support PUT (and PATCH, etc).

The `client.put()` function now needs to be filled in a little differently (I was unable to get it to work with `SimpleUploadedFile`) as explained here: https://fodra.github.io/2017/05/31/testing-django-rest-api-with-image-field.html

Comment: [django.test.Client.put documentation...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.put)